# String Methods: For 8-bit strings, this method is locale-dependent

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've tried to figure out what 'locale-dependent' means in relation with the `string methods` as `isalpha`, `isdigit`, `islower`, `isDigit` have that following line in the doc's

```
For 8-bit strings, this method is locale-dependent.
```

What is locale?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locale_(computer_software)

Comment: Also https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html

Comment: Is this python 2? Can you reference the relevant doc?

Answer (score 0):

Locale is the differences in how things are encoded based on how things are done in a geographic region. Typically this means things like how some regions might display today's date as `17 May, 2018` vs `May 17, 2018`, or how some regions will use `.` as a thousands separator and `,` as a fractional separator, like `9.000,1`.

You can find more information about the specifics of Python locale in the python docs:  https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/locale.html